# Count value from table column

Tags: mysql, sql

first I have a table which is pivot looks like this

```
pivot_product_Id | productsxx_Id | category_Id | subcategory_Id | color_Id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1         |        1        |      1    |      1         |   1
       2         |        1        |      1    |      1         |   2
       3         |        3        |      1    |      1         |   3
       4         |        4        |      1    |      2         |   4
       5         |        4        |      1    |      2         |   5
       6         |        2        |      2    |      4         |   6
       7         |        5        |      2    |      5         |   7
```

and I have color table like this

```
color_Id   | color   |  color2
------------------------------------------
    1      |  black   | white
    2      |  blue    | orange
    3      |  white   | black
    4      |  purple  | black
    5      |  black   | green
    6      |  red     | black
```

and my question is in category ID 1 or 2 ... how many black color exist ?  Counting from both color and color2 columns

and I tryed something like this but not geting the result I want and need help to create right query.

```
if(isset($shoes_post_var) || isset($nightwear_post_var)|| isset($outwear_post_var)){

                    $query3 = "SELECT count(*)
                FROM pivot
            JOIN category ON
                pivot.category_Id = category.category_Id
            JOIN subcategory ON
                pivot.subcategory_Id = subcategory.subcategory_Id       
            JOIN color ON
                pivot.color_Id = color.color_Id

            JOIN productsxx ON      
                pivot.productsxx_Id = productsxx.productsxx_Id
            WHERE  
             color IN ('$black') 
            or
             color2 IN ('$black')
            AND
            category IN ('$shoes_post_var','$nightwear_post_var','$outwear_post_var')
            GROUP BY pivot.color_Id  ASC ";
        $query5 = mysql_query($query3)or die(mysql_errno());
            $total = mysql_result($query5, 0);  
        echo ' '.'('.$total.')';}
```

Comment: Create and debug query as a plain text in phpmyadmin, mysql console or your favourite DB management tool. **ONLY AFTER** you get the query that works - move it to php. The same for questions - if you ask about mysql, remove everything that isn't relevant to query - any php code in this case.

Comment: using phpmyadmin,gona look at it.

Comment: so how about showing the *real query*?

Comment: I just add the php for to show and be clear to What I mean

Comment: it doesn't make it clear. If you're asking about a sql query - then another irrelevant code makes understanding harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM pivot 
 WHERE category_id IN (1, 2)
   AND color_id IN
( 
  SELECT color_id
    FROM color
   WHERE color = 'black' 
      OR color2 = 'black'
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85cd7/9)** demo

Comment: You do realise that sub-select is usually much slower than a join.

Comment: @AleksG Usually doesn't mean that it's true in that particular case, does it? Although I agree in general.

Answer (score 0):

You only described two tables and asked about a query based on these two tables.  This is a matter of a simple join with a simple selection - and a count - something like this:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM pivot
JOIN color ON (pivot.color_id=color.color_id AND 'black' in (color.color, color.color2))
WHERE pivot.category_id = 1
```

Feel free to change the `where` clause for other categories.

However your existing code joins 5 tables and uses some other selection criteria.  You really do need to ask the right question.  Don't try to ask one thing while implying another.

Comment: DBMS **do have** optimizations for `COUNT(*)` while `COUNT(1)` would be treated as `COUNT()` applied for the `1` integer literal which is just confusing and doesn't have any real reason to use, or does it?

Comment: @zerkms Not sure about optimisation for `count(*)` but for the past 20 years I've been taught that `count(1)` is faster.  This is due to the fact that for `count(*)` an index or a table (if no index exists) scan is required to retrieve values, while `count(1)` users internal row id's - which is quicker.  Last time I did a like-for-like comparison on a postgres table with 100 million rows, `count(1)` was about 5 times faster than `count(*)`

Comment: @AleksG Did you do such comparison using MySql?

Comment: "This is due to the fact that for `count(*)` an index or a table (if no index exists) scan is required to retrieve values" --- it's not. Mysql doesn't do a scan for `COUNT(*)`. "Last time I did a like-for-like comparison on a postgres table with 100 million rows, count(1) was about 5 times faster than count(*)" --- I don't believe that until I see the execution plans for that :-)

Comment: Just checked for postgresql 8.4 (on a small table with 60k rows) - the execution plans are identical.

Comment: To be even more precise: there is a special case `COUNT_SYM '(' opt_all '*' ')'` in mysql's SQL parser. Which (surprise for me!!!) uses `Item *item= new (YYTHD->mem_root) Item_int((int32) 0L,1);` as a parameter :-) So seems like for mysql `COUNT(*)` is absolutely identical to `COUNT(0)`

Comment: @peterm: seems like I've "made" a comparison (I hope it will be interesting for you) :-)